# Mongoose метод find() не вызывает колбэк

Tags: node.js, mongoose

В проекте имеется две монгусовские модели: User и Game. Для модели юзера все методы работают как надо, а вот в Game метод find отказывается работать:

```
var mongoose = require('../lib/mongoose.js');
var User = require('../models/user').User;
var Game = require('../models/game').Game;

User.find(function(err, users) {
    if(err) throw err;

    console.log("users: "); //здесь все хорошо
    console.log(users);
});

Game.find(function(err, games) {
    if(err) throw err; //ошибки не выбрасывает

    console.log("games: "); //не добирается до этой строки
    console.log(games);
});
```

Однако если вызвать count, то отрабатывает нормально для обеих коллекций:

```
User.count(function(err, count) {
    console.log("users count: " + count); //выводит 2
});

Game.count(function(err, count) {
    console.log("games count: " + count); //выводит 3
});
```

Подключаюсь к БД вот так:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var config = require('../config');

mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;
mongoose.connect(config.get('mongoose:uri'), config.get('mongoose:options'));

module.exports = mongoose;
```

Пытался через queries, лучше не стало

Comment: Чего find...?..

Comment: @YuriyPo хочу вывести все записи в коллекции

Comment: `find({}, function`

Comment: @YuriyPo пробовал, тоже не пашет

Answer (score 0):

Сразу проверь подключился ли твой скрипт вообще в базе:

```
const db = mongoose.connection;
db.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'connection error:'));
db.once('open', () => {
  console.log("h");
});
```

Используй промисы bluebird:

```
const bluebird = require('bluebird');
mongoose.Promise = bluebird;
```